# C. How to get the first N digits from a number depending on it's size (e.g. number = 1234 n = 2)

Tags: c

Is there a way in C to do the following:

I want to extract the degrees for a longitude reading in a NMEA sentence and a longitude comes in the format of:

```
xxxnn.nnnn
```

where the xxx's represent the degrees, and the n's represent the actual longitude value.

Now, I want be able to extract the value of xxx from this number and use it in the calculation in order to convert the longitude reading to its correct position based on the degrees.

The problem has extra complexity though, if a reading is at 4 degrees then the value will be stored as

```
xnn.nnnn
```

so is there a way to say, return the value of the x digits? in Java I stored the number as a String, and used substring to do this.

Example results:

```
if longitude =  1146.8937 I want to return 11
if longitude = 17829.8172 I want to return 178
if longitude =   123.3424 I want to return 1
```

Comment: From your examples, simply put, do you want to obtain the digits before the decimal point that are not the first two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Won't `(int) floor(longtitude) / 100` do ?

It's in `math.h`. Link it using `-lm`, like this:

`gcc program.c -o program -lm`

---

**EDIT**

As mentioned  in the comments below, `floor()` is indeed not needed in this case.

A simple cast to `int` and fixing the sign as you want it, will do.

Comment: i was not aware there was a floor function in C. Ill check the man pages now!

Comment: Thanks, I was already using the maths library but I haven't seen floor in C before, I should have looked there first!

Comment: @chrisedwards floor isn't needed and is wrong ... see ThoAppelsin's answer.

Comment: @chrisedwards `floor` is not what you want because degrees may be negative, in which case it will round "up" to the next negative degree. You want truncation, a.k.a. round toward zero. This is the default rounding mode in C, so all you need to do is cast the result to `int`, and that happens even without saying anything!

Answer (score 3):

Rather just use `(int) longitude / 100` *without the `floor`* if you want to obtain the digits before the decimal point, excluding the first two; accurately for both positive and negative values.

`(int) floor( longitude ) / 100` would result in `-10` for `longitude = -999.36`, for example.

If you want positive outcome strictly, then use if conditions or a [ternary operator](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a#C) like this:

```
( longitude > 0 ) ? (int) longitude / 100 : (int) longitude / -100
```

Answer (score 1):

Everyone is making this too complicated. `int degrees = longitude / 100;` will suffice.

Do not use `floor` because it will cause negative values to be rounded further from zero. The default rounding mode when assigning floating-point values to integer variables in C is toward zero, also known as truncation, or throwing out the fraction.

If the `nn.nnnn` digits were fractional degrees, then one could argue that the floating-point division `/ 100` could cause rounding to the next degree due to imprecision. But this is impossible because `nn.nnnn` stores minutes, which max out at 60.

If you need to separate the sign from the magnitude, use `abs` as normal. Do not do this at the same time as you are doing something else, for heaven's sake.

Just keep it simple.

Comment: Thanks, I was running some tests I found out that floor caused negative values under certain conditions.